# Компилятор nodejs приложений

Tags: node.js, typescript, компиляция, плагин, babel

Есть ли сейчас "компиляторы" с базой плагинов, которые специализируются на трансформировании кода nodejs? Из вариантов нашел babel - но не уверен что это задача этой библиотеки. Из плагинов нужны typescript, обфускатор, абсолютной путь в импортах... Список может пополняться

Comment: `Webpack` - можно тонко настроить и на тайпскрипт и на обфускацию и на абсолютные пути, готовых решений не видел.

Comment: Пробовал. Есть побочный эффект - webpack старается собирать бандл или наоборот сплитить общие части. А в проекте нужна компиляция 1 к 1

Comment: В целом можно взять любой таск-менеджер и уже в нём настроить нужные вам задачи. Из тех что пробовал лично, могу предложить Gulp. В нём точно можно реализовать то, что вы описали из готовых пакетов + достаточно много других плагинов. В то же время есть смысл посмотреть на Grunt и Bower

Comment: rollup может в мульти entry point, да вебпак тоже может по идее, главное его настроить, он тогда будет собирать файл один к одному

Comment: @ThisMan, пробовал эти варианты. Не получилось, потому что создавалить доп. бандлы из-за оптимизаций

Comment: @Ein, gulp, grunt и bower еще не смотрел, буду изучать